# Symfony 4 Disable CamelCase in Normalizer

Tags: symfony, serialization

In Symfony 4, I'm using `symfony/serialize`r to normalize Objects into arrays:

```
 $encoders     = [new JsonEncoder()];
 $normalizers  = [new ObjectNormalizer(null,null)];                   
 $this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);



$normalized = $this->serializer->normalize($user); // this normalize user and change the prop name to dateOfCreation
```

My user `Entity` is like:

```
   class User {
       /**
       * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
       * @SerializedName("date_of_creation")
       */
       private date_of_creation;

     }
```

How disable the camelCase conversion?

Comment: First of all if I was you I would follow [Symfony Naming Conventions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions) first and stick with camelCase for property names not snake_case as you do. In such case, whether your request payload has `date_of_creation` or `dateOfCreation` propery, it would be mapped to `private $dateOfCreation;` property. If you wanted to return snake case in response, you would then use `serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case` as `$nameConverter` property.

Comment: @BentCoder but sometimes we have to adhere to other's interfaces, such as remote APIs. Sure we could camelCase our internal then have a mapper but for simple things sometimes it is what it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#camelcase-to-snake-case) as Normalizer

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter());
```